# Date change question: Find and replace with wildcards?

Tags: search, cut-copy-paste, substitute, replace, date-and-time

I have a file with a bunch of dates of the form `a/b/c`, where `a`,`b`, and `c` are numbers of varying character length. However, I'd like to change every instance to read `c/a/b`.

> I'm wondering if there is a command to use the "find and replace" functionality that can also use multiple wildcards?

I have not found a way to do this using the `:s` documentation.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @filbranden thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:%s,\v(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+),\3/\1/\2,g
```

- `s` is the substitution command, the `%` before it means that all lines of the file will be considered.
- `,` is the separator. It is common to choose `/` as the separator, but since there are slashes in the pattern and replacement, it is useful to choose another separator, so as to avoid escaping.
- `\v` enables very magic mode, so that special symbols
  such as `+()` do not need to be escaped.
- `(\d+)` is the a capture group, capturing digits.
- `g` indicates that all matches in a line should be replaced, not only the first match.

The substitution is done by reordering the groups as `\3/\1/\2`.

Sample input before

```
01/02/2020 1111/123/21
12/11/1212 VIM 10/1/1
ABC
```

and after the command

```
2020/01/02 21/1111/123
1212/12/11 VIM 1/10/1
ABC
```

You can find more on the substitute command at `:help :s`.

Comment: I think to get the ordering I was after, I had to end with ```\3/\1\2``` but that pretty much gets it, easy enough to remove the lagging ```/``` on each occurance. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Sorry! I read it too fast, it should be correct now. Glad to help!

Comment: What is the purpose of the `,` after `%s` ?

Comment: @guntbert It is not so usual, you may be familiar with `/` instead. But "picket fences" would be required if we sticked with slashes: `%s/\v(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/\3\/\1\/\2/g`. I have edited the answer to include that, check it out

Comment: @Quasímodo oh, of course - I am used to using other delimiters but the comma threw me :-/